# Big-O notation for a simple function and why

Tags: python, big-o

What would be the big-O notation for a simple function like:

```
def function(array, index):
    return array[index]
```

Would it be linear because the it looks at each cell in the array? or constant? And why?

Comment: It's constant because no matter how big your input is it accesses exactly one thing.

Comment: Constant.  It doesn't look at each cell, it looks at only one.

Comment: O(1): see https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: @Casey: how do you know? What is `array` here? What if it is a linked list?

Comment: @DavidHoelzer: that is *assuming* that accessing that cell can be done in constant time.

Comment: @dfri: that makes the assumption that this is a standard Python type.

Comment: The OP's "...each cell in the array..." tends to imply that this is not nearly as complicated as you are making it @MartijnPieters

Comment: @DavidHoelzer: of course it is. It is a function that delegates an operation to an object of unknown type. Perhaps the question is sadly underspecified, but that *never* happens, right?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Well, I don't know Python, but the parameter is called `array` and apparently supports indexed access, so I thought it was a reasonable assumption.  But if we're going to assume no assumptions at all are valid how do I even know that an indexed access to this object returns the item at that index?  There's no reason it couldn't do something totally different.

Comment: @Casey: exactly. So there is nothing we can say other than that the complexity depends entirely on the object passed in.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on the type of object. If `array` is a Python list object, it'll be O(1). If it is a linked list, it'll be O(n). If it is a binary tree, it could be O(log n).

In other words, a function that does nothing but delegate an operation to another object has no clear complexity. It is entirely dependent on the cost of that one operation.